# mailbox.item.body.getAsync call fails when attempting to fetch a very large mail body

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

When attempting to call [`mailbox.item.body.getAsync()`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.3/Body#getasynccoerciontype-options-callback) using Outlook 2016 for Mac, we are receiving a timeout (i.e. the callback is never executed).

The size of the message is `~329KB` (`329324` characters) and can be fetched when the coercion type is set `Text` and only fails when requesting the `HTML` content.

We have tested this on Outlook 2016 for Windows and have not been able to reproduce the issue with the exact same message.

Is this a possible bug with the Office API for Outlook 2016 for Mac?

Comment: Is there by chance a hidden image in the body of the email (i.e. `style="display:none;"`)?

Comment: I just checked our test mail and it does not have any hidden images

Comment: Thanks for raising it. We are looking into it and update the thread.

Comment: Tried out the following code snippet in read and compose mode with 1 million characters and the callback function is being called. Kindly retry with the given code snippet :

`Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync('html',
 function(res) {
  console.log('callback');
 }
);`

Comment: This is not working only in Outlook 2016 for Mac. I will confirm again.

Comment: I am still able to reproduce the issue.